# Database Design for Simple Private Messaging

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

The concept is simple:

1. User click "Send PM" button on one of ads.
2. Window pop up with "Title" box, "Message" box and send button.
3. Recipient sees a message with following info: "Sender Name", "Date Received", "Title" and "Message".
4. Recipient replies by filling: "Title" and "Message" and press reply.
5. Repeat step 3.

No IP will be stored.

**Can you please give me an idea how to make a concise/efficient relational design?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message table formate

**Message**

```
Id 
UserID
Message
Send_DateTime
Title
Message_Id ( FK )- self referance
```

self referance is to keep the track of the whole chat.

for the first message its NULL and than onwards id of relative meesage

```
Id     UserID    Message    Send_DateTime    Title    Message_Id ( FK )- self referance
1       1         test       datetime        tt       Null
2       2         test1      datetime        tt        1
3       1         test2      datetime        tt        2
...

go on
```

Comment: Most i probably i will take your answer, can you please explain what the self-reference for?

Comment: Great .... I Just would like to say, the replied response won't have the sender's message tacked to it .... THANKS! ....

Comment: If you are going to pull data from an entire chat (multiple messages between 2 users), then you should use another table that references the message id, most likely called "MessageThread" with the message_id column.  That way you're only doing a single lookup to get an entire chat, not 1 scan per message.